# What are the alternatives to swpackage?

Tags: hp-ux, swinstall

I want to package a software for HP-UX (SD-UX) on a GNU/Linux operating system(for CI/CD reasons) but seems that swpackage is available only on HP-UX. What are the alternatives to swpackage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errr... Found it elsewhere for GNU/Linux. See [GNU.org's version](https://www.gnu.org/software/swbis/swpackage_8.html) .

Comment: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/swbis